# cURL requests blocks IP after 1 request

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have a simple terminal shell command here:

```
curl -v -m 60 -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nb;q=0.6' -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3" http://imeidata.net -e http://imeidata.net/iphone/model-check http://imeidata.net/iphone/model-check?sn=C8PKTRF5DTC1
```

- When I run it for first time I get full result (Page is about 23KB)
- When I run this command for second time I get only a sample page
  (about 17KB)

I am still able to visit this website, so my IP is not blocked but only cURL request are denied.

Again if I change my IP.. same will happen.
Why do my requests get blocked?

Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I would fire it with "-k" @ the end of the request.

So fire your request + " -k" like below:

```
   curl -v -m 60 -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nb;q=0.6' -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3" http://imeidata.net -e http://imeidata.net/iphone/model-check http://imeidata.net/iphone/model-check?sn=C8PKTRF5DTC1 -k
```

Comment: Could you explain what the `-k` does?

Comment: I tried with -k in end but there is no difference. Tried with new IP.. Still gets blocked.

Comment: Yes, if you fire it with " -k" (mind the space is required) at the end, it allows connections to ssl sites without certificates.  I find in a lot of my cURL calls, to debug phantomJS scrapes I need to fire them with the -k parameter.  I'm not actually certified as a logged in viewer I just need the page to be forced to respond to my call as if I was. " -k" forces cURL calls to do just that.  That's the simplest explanation I can provide.

Comment: What if you were to remove "-m 60" and try again?

Comment: I removed "-m 60" and also tired to use " --insecure" insted of " -k" but both gives same result.. With or without -k is still same as before.

Comment: Question, what is your end goal with this cURL call?  I'm wondering if you're more verbose with your cURL statement than you need to be.  Did you try calling the final page directly without referer pages?

Comment: I need data from this page which I will process with grep later. I have tried to call the final page directly, its same if I request this page with referrer or without. I was thinking maybe it will help to define a referer but it doesn't.

Comment: I don't want to extend this discussion much further as stack is recommending to move it to a chat instead, but I would say to run fiddler2 or wireshark in the bkg and watch what the page is responding with when you make your following cURL calls.  Maybe there's something simple you're missing. I'm not having any trouble hitting the pages again and again using cygwin/cURL (https://www.wireshark.org/) or (http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler2) you could even stay online and try (https://www.hurl.it/) which runs very similarly to cURL but analyzes only the current req/res bodies

Comment: I tried.. My cURL calls is not blocked either. When I visit this link from fresh IP I get 22KB in response. Second cURL give me 17KB in response. What I understand: My second call enables Google Java Recaptcha, therefore cURL dont shows results cause Google is blocking. Just did 5500 cURL now with 5500 IPs.. Can I prevent Google Recaptcha? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure, but there are some good add-ins for converting captcha to audio and submitting, you may want to look into that.  Stiltwalker was very effective until Google nerfed it's newest version.  They are pretty fast at re-releasing though so I'd keep an eye on them as one of your best bets.  But if there's a reCaptcha you need to find an audio-reader and submission tool as your best bet.  Your only other option being to consistently recreate your outgoing call so it continues to re-grab all the data, but that sounds cumbersome and likely rather slow.